# What is the name of a triangular array in which each element is the sum of the left path and right path?

Tags: matrices, binomial-coefficients

I was writing a recursive computer algorithm to find the [optimal matrix multiplication order](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matrix-chain-multiplication-dp-8/) (without using memoizing anything, so I am recomputing a lot). Quite interestingly, the triangle below emerged from the number of times each recursive function with different parameters is called. For example, the top of the tree represents the first call: `M(1, n)`. Let `M(i, j)` be the optimal solution to multiplying Matrix `i` to `j` with the least amount of multiplications. Then, in the context of this problem, `M(i, j)` actually gets its solution by calling `M` $2  (j-i)$ more, with "smaller" paramters, of course.

Anyways, I don't know if this problem matters much, but we have this cute triangle below. Is there a name for this triangle? Additionally, is it possible to compute an explicit formula for this (I think the recursive definition is $a_{n, m} = a_{n, m-1} + a_{n+1, m-1}$ and $a_{1, 1} = 1$, where $m$ is the height of the node in the triangle below and $n$ is the index of the node counting from the left )?

I would also appreciate any additional mathematical insights into the nature of this, I am not so adept at it.

[image: Sum of left right path triangle]

Comment: A quick OEIS search found [A035002](https://oeis.org/A035002) is your array.